# How do I retrieve the json representation of an azure data factory pipeline?

Tags: json, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I want to track pipeline changes in source control, and I'm looking for a way to programmatically retrieve the json representation from the ADF.

The .Net routines return the objects, but sadly ToString() does not return json (wouldn't THAT be convenient?), so right now I'm looking at copying the json down by hand (shoot me now!), or possibly trying to recreate the json from the .Net objects (shoot me later!).

Please tell me I'm being dense and there is an obvious way to do this.

Comment: There is a visual studio extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/371a4cf9-0093-40fa-b7dd-be3c74f49005) which gives you a project template you can check in.  However this would not solve the problem of a user going directly to azure and modifying the json.

Comment: This is fine for manual dumps, but I'm really trying to get the human (me) out of the loop. Humans make mistakes, forget to do tasks, get hit by meteorites (technically it's still a meteor when it hits someone, isn't it?). In any case, I want to make myself redundant, but can't quite see how to do it.

Comment: Where is the development of the ADF pipelines taking place?  How many people on the team are creating pipelines? If all work on pipelines was done through VS with the ADF template that would solve the problem, more of a policy solution then technical one.  If you really wanted to get a json representation of the objects couldn't you just serialize them with newtonsoft json.net?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the object using Newtonsoft Json. 
See (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-data-factories-programmatically/) for how to connect via the ADF SDK

```
var aadTokenCredentials = new TokenCloudCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionId"], GetAuthorizationHeader());

var resourceManagerUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceManagerEndpoint"]);
var manager = new DataFactoryManagementClient(aadTokenCredentials, resourceManagerUri);
var pipeline = manager.Pipelines.Get(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, pipelineName);
var pipelineAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pipeline.Pipeline, Formatting.Indented);
```

I was expecting something more complex but looking at the sdk source GitHub it is not doing anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Our team has a deployment tool that takes git changes and deploy them appropriately. Everything is done asynchronously and being controlled and versioned through git. 
In a nutshell our deployment has the following flow:

- Any completed git merge request triggers a VSO build. This is simply
     building the whole solution via MsBuild.
- Every successful build is applied a Git tag for tracking of Last Known Good.
- Next (if build succeeded) our .net ADFPublisher starts by taking only the changed data factory files and asynchronously publishing them based on their
     git operation (modified, add, delete, etc.).
- For some failures cases our ADFPublisher will perform a retry.

  This whole process (Build + publish) takes ~ 65 seconds and has
  already saved us from having several bugs. It also allows us to move
  definitions from one environment to another very easily.

Let me know if you think this is something that you will be interested in and I will setup a way to share it with you